# $f=g \implies \int_{A} f dm = \int_A g dm$, why can one assume set $N=\{x \in A: f(x) \not= g(x)\}$ in proof?

Tags: measure-theory

In proving: $f=g$ for almost every $x$ $\implies \int_{A} f dm = \int_A g dm$

why can one then assume set $N=\{x \in A: f(x) \not= g(x)\}$?

Isn't this assuming against the assumption?

Comment: why can one assume $\textbf{what}$ about N?

Comment: @juandiegorojas I mean if one is to assume $f=g$, then why does one assume the set where $f \not= g$, yet proves that the integrals equals. So it's not antithesis.

Comment: The antecedent of the implication, "$f = g$ for almost every $x$" (which isn't impeccably formulated), means just that the set $\{x : f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is a null set (with respect to the measure $m$). It may be empty of course.